# How do i get the url of certificate generated using prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

i know how to render it in webapp but i'm supposed to generate pdf through an api call , so i need to send url of the pdf generated instead of the pdf itself ( thats what the mobile developer is asking for ) , is there any way to do it ?

like:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      pdf = CustomCertificatePdf.new(current_user, tutorials)
      url = pdf.link
      # send_data pdf.render, filename: "custom_certificate_#{current_user.first_name.downcase}_#{current_user.last_name.downcase}.pdf",
                # type: "application/pdf",
                # disposition: "inline"
      render :json => {url: url}
    end
  end
```

even your slight hint will be appreciated , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing

```
pdf = CustomCertificatePdf.new(current_user, tutorials)
  @filename = File.join("custom_certificate_#{current_user.first_name.downcase}_#{current_user.last_name.downcase}.pdf")
  pdf.render_file @filename
  current_user.cust_cert = File.open("custom_certificate_#{current_user.first_name.downcase}_#{current_user.last_name.downcase}.pdf")
  current_user.save!

  render :json => {url: "#{current_user.cust_cert}"}
```

in user model

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :cust_cert,
                        :default_url => "",
                        :path           => ':attachment/:id/:cust_cert',
                        :storage        => :s3,
                        :url            => ':s3_domain_url',
                        :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')



validates_attachment_content_type :cust_cert, :content_type => [ 'application/pdf' ], :if => :cust_cert_attached?

def cust_cert_attached?
    self.cust_cert.file?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

save pdf to `public` folder or upload to another server( S3, google drive, dropbox, ...)
then use that link in api controller

if you save pdf file in `public` folder, the link should be your host name + relative path with `public` folder

ex:

```
file_path = "/webapp/public/pdf/custom_certificate.pdf"
```

the link should be

```
http://yourhostname.com/pdf/custom_certificate.pdf
```

If you need protect your file, you should write another controller to serve it with authentication

Comment: yeah , i understood what you said and tried it via S3 and solved it. Thanks